# Android Facebook Open Graph type Reference error

Tags: android, facebook-opengraph, facebook-oauth

I am getting the following error when I am trying to post my Facebook Open Graph Action.

Here is how I am submitting the code.

```
JSONObject test = new JSONObject();
test.put("type","myappnamespace:myCustomType");
test.put("title","test");
test.put("url","http://samples.ogp.me/314782891908537");
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("access_token", GetAccessToken(mContext));
params.putString("myCustomType", test.toString());
AsyncFacebookRunner request = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
request.request("me/myappnamespace:myCustomAction", params, "POST", new addToTimelineListener(), null);
```

Error:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#3503) \"{
\"type\":\"myappnamespace:myCustomType\",
\"url\":\"http:\\\/\\\/samples.ogp.me\\\/314782891908537\",
\"title\":\"test\"}\" 
is an invalid value for property \"myCustomType\" with type 
"Reference\"","type":"OAuthException","code":3503}}
```

Even though it says its an OAuthException it doesn't have anything to do with my access token. Because I can use the same token to post feeds to Facebook with the app.

Comment: This was answered in a previous post [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271536/post-an-object-of-type-reference